# How to invoke a softkeypad when an edittext is clicked and disappear click outside the edittext

Tags: android

Can anybody tell How to invoke a soft-keypad when an edit text is clicked and disappear click outside the edit text?Can anybody provide Code?

Answer (score 0):

Set inputType in xml for EditText it will automatically open the keyboard.

To hide keyboard use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

To show keyboard forcefully use this

```
InputMethodManager imm = this.(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: but it is not open the keypad?

Comment: If its not opening automatically check if EditText has focus set. Other alternate is I am editing in my previous answer.

Comment: add `<requestFocus/>` inside your edittext widget in xml.Keyboard will open

Answer (score 0):

When you will click inside an edittext, soft keyboard will open up. To hide the keyboard, press the back button or press anywhere on the screen outside the edittext. For that use this code :-

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: no when i click the edit text it is not showing the invoke softkeypad